# Как правильно выводить спарсенные данные в listview, cardview, список?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup, listview

Есть некий набор строковых данных `ArrayList<String> strings`, который мы получаем путем парсинга некоторой веб-страницы. Парсинг, естественно, происходит в отдельном потоке, но когда я пытаюсь вывести эти данные в `cardview` или просто `listview` с помощью адаптера, то никакие данные не приходят.
Данные отобразятся, только если принудительно попросить главный поток дождаться выполнения побочного. Вот так:

```
try {
        strings = stringsTask.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Как можно избежать подобной конструкции? Предполагаю, что нужно в  `onPostExecute()` таска, что-то указать, но не знаю что.
Указанный там `MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` не работает (т.е. после полной загрузки всех данных, данные все равно не обновляются).
Я постарался понятно объяснить свою проблему, но если мне не удалось, напишите пожалуйста об этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не надо делать адаптер статическим полем активити.
2. В onPostExecute вам в качестве аргумента приходят ваши данные. Именно в этом методе вам надо создать адаптер с ними,
3. Присвоить его `ListView` или `RecyclerView` или ещё чему-то.
4. Теперь можно вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged()` над адаптером.

Comment: а как же `context` который нужно использовать в адаптере?
а присваивать его `RecyclerView` разве получится, не объявляя ее `recyclerView` как статическую? Иначе, нужно будет создавать ее в этом же `onPostExecute`, но создать создадим, а найти не получится, поскольку `findViewById` там использовать нельзя.

Comment: @whalemare, просто передайте в `AsyncTask` контекст и `Recycler` в качестве аргументов конструктора и присвойте их полям класса. Так в `onPostExecute` вы сможете адаптер создать, присвоить и контекст использовать.

Comment: тооочно.. Я почему-то решил, что в AsyncTask можно передать данные только через `nameAsync.execute(data)`, не вспомнив о конструкторе.. Спасибо огромное, за помощь!)

Comment: @whalemare, пожалуйста)